# What is the mathematical field of those images called?

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, random-walk

We have some function $f(n)$ which yields positive integer values and is defined for integer n.

**Example A**

We have a x-y-plane and start at $(0,0)$.

We will paint an image on the plane by drawing from the past point a new 1-unit line in a $$\dfrac{360}{N} \cdot (f(x) \mod N)$$ degrees angle.

**Example B**

We have a x-y-plane with squares and color $(0,0)$ black.

Depending on the value of $$\dfrac{360}{4} \cdot (f(x) \mod 4)$$
we paint the upper, lower, left or right square black and start from this square again, so that another image is created.

Self generated example, where the direction depends on the last digit of the next prime: [HERE](http://fschneider.info/ART.php#map)

**In what field of mathematics do we investigate such images/graphs/paths/maps?**

I have been thinking whether

- topology or
- random walk theory or
- graph theory

investigates such images/graphs/paths/maps (?), but those *paths* are neither random nor is this a actual graph.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics, in particular (or in general, depending on your interests) iterated function systems. See [the related wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system).

Comment: i think fractals is not the right area, because it is absolutely not about self-similarity etc., but could you give another link concerning Dynamics?

Comment: [Fractals are typically not self-similar](https://youtu.be/gB9n2gHsHN4)

Comment: Thank you, can you still give me some more details on how my examples fit into the field of Dynamics / Iterated Function Systems ? E.g. is says ' The fractal is made up of the union of several copies of itself, each copy being transformed by a function (hence "function system").' and this is not what my example is about...

Comment: Dynamics studies how a space is transformed under an evolution map, given that that evolution map is well-defined and fixed for some time interval. The general scheme is to have an object $X$ in some category and an endomorphism $f$ of it, and then to look at the orbits of points under the iterations of $f$. In particular we are concerned if a certain simplistic rule can create patterns and/or irregularities. This I believe is what you are interested in as well. Taking unions corresponds to printing the previous picture each time you add something to it in your case.

Comment: (I might be able to give a more precise answer, if you can provide further details, e.g. in what properties of these shapes are you interested in, what kinds of $f$ do you choose, do you want to utilize the algebraic properties of $\Bbb{Z}_n$ in some way or do you use it only to define a finite number of directions etc.)